# Datetime from string doesn't match

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to match a specific datetime format from a string but I am receiving a `ValueError` and I am not sure why. I am using the following format:

```
t = datetime.datetime.strptime(t,"%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S.%f Eastern Standard Time")
```

which is an attempt to match the following string:

```
Nov 19, 2017 20:09:14.071360000 Eastern Standard Time
```

Can anyone see why these do not match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by [pault](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49457812/6671176) and the documentation, the issue is that the `%f` directive is essentially limited to 6 decimal places for your microseconds. While their solution works fine for your string, you might have an issue if your string is something like

```
'Nov 19, 2017 20:09:14.071360123 Eastern Standard Time'
```

Because calling `rstrip('0')` in that case would not cut the microseconds to the proper length. You could otherwise do the same with regex:

```
import re
import datetime

date_string = 'Nov 19, 2017 20:09:14.071360123 Eastern Standard Time'
# use a regex to strip the microseconds to 6 decimal places:
new_date_string = ''.join(re.findall(r'(.*\.\d{6})\d+(.*)', date_string)[0])
print(new_date_string)
#'Nov 19, 2017 20:09:14.071360 Eastern Standard Time'

t = datetime.datetime.strptime(new_date_string,"%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S.%f Eastern Standard Time")    
print(t)
#datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 19, 20, 9, 14, 71360)
```

Comment: Your explanation is better than mine +1.

Answer (score 5):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) we can see that `%f` expects:

> Microsecond as a decimal number, zero-padded on the left.

The problem with your string is that you have a number that's zero-padded on the right.

Here is one way to fix your issue:

```
new_t = t.partition(" Eastern Standard Time")[0].rstrip('0') + ' Eastern Standard Time'
print(new_t)
#Nov 19, 2017 20:09:14.07136 Eastern Standard Time

t2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(new_t,"%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S.%f Eastern Standard Time")
print(t2)
#datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 19, 20, 9, 14, 71360)
```

Comment: See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49458021/5858851) by sacul which has a better explanation than what I have provided.